# Is possible to use INSERT INTO first_table SELECT from second_table, where first table is from /var/one.db and second_table is from /tmp/second.db?

Tags: sqlite, pdo

Is possible to use INSERT INTO first_table SELECT from second_table, where first table is from /var/one.db and second_table is from /tmp/second.db ?. I need to use PHP PDO and SQLITE3. I cannot merger this two tables in same sqlite db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sqlite3 it is not possible to merge tables from different databases. It is annoying but thats how it is. 
We can merge different database tables in SQLServer or POSTGRESQL or MYsql. (not sure of all though but need little googling).